# How do I stop my count variable incrementing incorrectly in my Applet?

Tags: java

I am using a button in my Applet to add words to a LinkedList. It however is currently not working correctly. It seems like every time the "Add word" button is selected it holds the previous number as the count value and is incrementing with the old value instead of just going up in 1's each time. This is causing the incorrect value to be printed when the search button is selected and the wrong number is outputted. How do I make the count variable hold the correct value despite the number of times "Add word" is selected.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/**
 * Created by joshuaogunnote on 31/10/2015.
 */

public class Applet2 extends JApplet {

    private String text;
    private int text1;
    JTextField value1, value2;
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    public JLabel jLabel;
    public int count = 0;
    public int search_count = 0;

    public void init() {

        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Please enter a word");
        JLabel prompt1 = new JLabel("Please enter a certain letter");

        value1 = new JTextField(10);
        value2 = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.add(prompt);
        textPanel.add(value1);
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textPanel.add(prompt1);
        textPanel.add(value2);


        JPanel centrePanel = new JPanel();
        text = "";
        jLabel = new JLabel(text);
        centrePanel.add(jLabel);
        add(centrePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JButton but = new JButton("Add word");
        JButton but1 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("Remove first occurrence");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("Remove all occurrences");
        JButton but4 = new JButton("Display all words begging with certain letter");
        JButton but5 = new JButton("Search");

        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();

        butPanel.add(but);
        butPanel.add(but1);
        butPanel.add(but5);
        butPanel.add(but2);
        butPanel.add(but3);
        butPanel.add(but4);


        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        but.addActionListener(new AddHandler(this));
        but1.addActionListener(new ClearHandler(this));
        but5.addActionListener(new SearchHandler(this));
        but2.addActionListener(new RemoveFirstHandler(this));


    }

    class AddHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public AddHandler(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            text = theApplet.value1.getText();


            try {

                text1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
                jLabel.setText("ERROR - The string " + "'" + text1 + "'" + " is not a valid word");

            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

                if (text.length() != 0) {
                    jLabel.setText("Word " + "'" + text + "'" + " has been added to the list");
                    list.add(text);
```

This is the variable.

```
                    count = count + 1;

                } else {
                    jLabel.setText("ERROR - Please enter a word");
                }

            }

        }
    }

    class ClearHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public ClearHandler(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            list.clear();
            jLabel.setText("List has been cleared");
            count = 0;
            search_count = 0;

        }
    }

    class SearchHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public SearchHandler(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text = theApplet.value1.getText();

            ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();

            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {


                if (text.equals(listIterator.next())) {

                    search_count = search_count + 1;

                }
            }

            jLabel.setText("Word " + "'" + text + "'" + " was found " + search_count + " time(s) in the list");

            if (text.length() == 0) {

                jLabel.setText("Please enter a word - The total number of words in the list are: " + count);

            }

        }
    }

    class RemoveFirstHandler implements ActionListener {

        private Applet2 theApplet;

        public RemoveFirstHandler(Applet2 app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();

            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {

                if (text.equals(listIterator.next())) {

                    list.remove(text);
                    jLabel.setText("First occurrence of word " + "'" + text + "'" + " has been deleted");
                    count = 0;
                    search_count = 0;
                    break;

                } else {

                    jLabel.setText("ERROR - Word " + "'" + text + "'" + " is not in list");
                }


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code is ridiculous. An Exception should be thrown if something fishy goes on, that you need to handle. Don't have Exceptions decide your non-Esceptional flow

Comment: Do you have any ideas on  how to implement it correctly then? I am trying to implement constraints such that my Textfields only accept strings without numbers.

Comment: I don't think it'll reset the value on clicking the button. have you debugged and followed the flow?

Comment: yes the value of count goes up in: 1,2,3,6,10,15,21,28

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing first, don't show this code to anyone. They would not be impressed. There are many ways to determine if the word entered is an Integer or not but using `NumberFormatException` is not one of them.

Instead you should use something like:

```
if(!text.trim().matches("[\\d]+")) {
   //the text entered is not an Integer. Do your magic here.
}
```

If you want that the text entered does not contains any number at all, use

```
Pattern and Matchers
Pattern pattern = Pattern.comile("[\\d]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(!matcher.find()) {
   //matcher was unable to find any number in the string
}
```

Internally you are maintaining a list of valid word which you call `list` you can use `list.size()` to find the number of valid words you have. You dont have to use a separate counter for that.